# Pagination Not Working With Custom Post Type Category

Tags: posts, pagination, custom-post-type-archives, customization

I can't get pagination to work with this custom post type category archive. The custom post type is called 'blog'.

```
<h2 class="category-h2">Blogs Category: <?php single_cat_title(); ?></h2>
<pre>
</pre>

<div class="row">
<?php

$my_cat_value = get_query_var('cat_value');
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'blog',
  'category_name' => $my_cat_value,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 10
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $query->posts;

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
  echo '<div class="col-6">';

  $title  = get_the_title();
  $url =  get_permalink();

  $authID = $post->post_author;
  $author = get_user_by( 'ID', $authID );
  $author_display_name = $author->display_name;

  //* Large image
  $image = get_field( 'acf_cb_header_image' );
  $size_m = 'cs_cb_medium';
  $url_m = $image[ 'sizes' ][ $size_m ];
  ?>

  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
  <?php

  if ( empty( $url_m ) ) {
    echo '&hellip;';  
  }
  else {
    echo '<img src="' . $url_m .'" class="responsive-image" width="340" height="190"></a>';
  }

  ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
  <?php
  echo '<h2 class="cb-archive-h2">' . $title . '</h2></a>';

  //* The Excerpt
  echo '<div class="custom-blog-content">';
  echo the_excerpt();
  echo '</div>';

  //* The Date
  echo '<span class="cb-meta-date">';
  echo get_the_date('M j, Y');
  echo '</span>';

  //* The Author
  echo '<span class="cb-meta-cat cb-meta-author">';
  // echo $author_display_name;
  echo '<a href="' . get_author_posts_url($post->post_author) . '">' . $author_display_name . '</a>';
  echo '</span>';

  echo '</div><!-- /col-6 -->';
}
?>
</div> <!-- /row -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'mid_size'  => 2 ) ); ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
  <?php
  //* Custom Blog Sidebar 
    dynamic_sidebar( 'blogs-sidebar' );
    ?>
</aside>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [category/category\_name pagination 404 error](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/357331/category-category-name-pagination-404-error)

Comment: what is the problem? no paginate links showing? the same or no posts on paginated pages? or what else?